# How does the code in Jupyter Notebook get executed in Ipython

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am new to jupyter and I modify the html content of the generated notebook when you click create new Notebook in Jupyter. I have added an html block that contains a jupyter code to display graph or markdown code. Now, does anybody know how do I use the jupyter javascripts to interpret my code and display it inside the jupyter notebook cell index 0?. If my question is not clear please let me know and would love to edit it.

currently, I see this code in jupyter main.min.js. But how do they get the code and send it to python.

```
'run-cell':{
        help    : 'run selected cells',
        help_index : 'bb',
        handler : function (env) {
            env.notebook.execute_selected_cells();
        }
    },
```

Comment: If you have the code you want to run as a string in Javascript, you can call `Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute('a=1')`.

Comment: @ThomasK I tried the code above but not working. Can we also programmatically set the cell codes in Jupyter in a specific cell(say lets cell index 0) and execute them using IPython.notebook.execute_cells([0]); and give it an output?.

Comment: @ThomasK This is what i found in the main.min.js in jupyter this.kernel.execute(this.get_text(), callbacks, {silent: false, store_history: true,stop_on_error : stop_on_error}); that get_text() is for the code. how to supply those other parameter? can I leave it empty?